# Unable to do reindexing in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, reindex

I am getting Issue while reindexing . I tried with ssh also but its not done. Can any one help me on this

http://screencast.com/t/nfSCJPMq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arises when you have some problem with your attributes.
Are you getting some error like `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '114-142-1-62' for key 'PRIMARY'`

In this case `114` is the product id and `142` is the attribute id that is causing the problem.
Go to that product change the attribute and save the product again. This should solve the re-indexing issue.

Comment: yes i am getting the same error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '12-199-1-5085'  i did for some products but still its comming by every time new product id & Attribute Id . Can we do this in bulk like through database

Comment: Yes you can update it using a script. Here's one for reference:
`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($ProductIds, array('attribute_code' => "some value"), $storeId);`

**$ProductIds** consists of the products ids in your store